# How to run a function with Tastypie API request?

Tags: jquery, python, django, cordova, tastypie

I'm creating an app which has a Cordova client (smartphone) side and a Django backend. The Django backend will retrieve data from another API (the League of Legends API) and process it in a python file containing a python function. In order to keep the app fast, I'm using Tastypie and AJAX from jQuery Mobile. So basically:

```
Django + Tastypie API ---JSON--> Cordova + AJAX
```

I have everything set up so that data can be put into and taken out of a database, but this is all I can do so far.

My plan is to be able to retrieve data from the LoL API, run the data processing function, add it to a database, and return the processed data to the client--all on request of the AJAX client. **This might be a 'noobish' question, but how can I run this certain function every time someone accesses my Tastypie API? And where should this function be called?** Perhaps in the api.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this function in the `api.py` or in the `models.py`, depending on what exactly you want to do.

The example below shows an example to run a function if you do a post at the url `/lol/`:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.utils import trailing_slash


class LolResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'lol'
        allowed_methods = ['post']  # note that this resource just accept posts

    def base_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('lol_api_function'), name="api_lol_api_function"),
        ]

    def lol_api_function(self, request, **kwargs):
        # you function
        pass
```

Do not forget to add the `LolResource` at your `urls.py`.

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense. I ended up just using Flask to make my life easier, but thanks for the response!